# VML alternative to SVG pattern (possibly using Raphael JS)

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, vml

In SVG it is possible to define a pattern that can be used as the fill for a path. For an example of what I mean you can check this link: [SVG pattern example](http://www.carto.net/papers/svg/samples/pattern1.svg). Unfortunately SVG is not usable in older versions of Internet Explorer, so I'll have to work with VML there.

To make my life a little more easy I use Raphaël JS (to be more specific, I use the draw package of ExtJS 4.0, which is based on Raphaël), so I don't have to worry about the differences between SVG and VML.

Raphael JS however, does not provide a way to define patterns and use them, so I'll have to do this by hand. In SVG this is not much of a problem, but in VML I cannot find a way to create a pattern and use it as the (repeating) background of a path.

The closest thing I have found is the ability to use an image as the background of a path, as described [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264135%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Pattern%20fill). The problem is I want to fill the path with a repeating vector image, so I can scale it and still have it look nice.

Any help in pointing me in the right direction for solving this would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** For people visiting my post: I've come to the conclusion that what I describe above is not possible. The only patterning possible in VML is tiling an image, using a [fill element](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-VML#_Toc416858394). Patterns made of vector shapes are not possible in VML.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to use an SVG image inside a VML shape?

Comment: No that is not what I mean, I'm sorry for being unclear on that. What I want is to use a pattern of VML shapes as the background for a VML shape, just as it is possible to use SVG shapes (defined in a pattern) as the fill for an SVG shape.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this method:

1- Create a bounding box with path element (not rect) of the path you want to fill.
2- Append "z" and the path string of the path you want to fill to the bounding box path string. This will create a clipped rect.
3- Use javascript for repeating pattern behind the clipped rect.